# How to convert an image object inside an ImageView to GrayScale with Android Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, image, xamarin

I have an image inside an `ImageView` in my Xamarin Android application. I have a button event handler with code to process the Bitmap inside the `ImageView` , get a GrayScale representation of that Bitmap and display the resulting image in the same ImageView.
However when I click on the `ConnvertToGrayScale` button when running the application on my phone, the application stops responding for a while and then responds after 15  seconds or so, then the image inside the `ImageView` is gone and then replaced by white content. Here is my code

**Code**

```
if (imageView.Drawable != null)
            {
                //loop through the bitmap
                try
                {
                    BitmapDrawable mymap = (BitmapDrawable)imageView.Drawable;
                    Bitmap map= mymap.Bitmap;
                    Bitmap new_map = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(map.Width, map.Height, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
                    ColorObject p;
                    for (int x = 0; x < map.Width; x++)
                    {
                        for (int y = 0; y < map.Height; y++)
                        {
                            p = map.GetColor(x, y);
                            //get the alpha of the color
                            float a = p.Alpha();
                            float r = p.Red();
                            float g = p.Green();
                            //define the gray scale
                            float gray = (a + r + g) / 3;
                            new_map.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Argb((int)a, (int)gray, (int)gray, (int)gray));

                        }
                    }
                    //assign to the image view
                    imageView.Invalidate();
                    imageView.SetImageBitmap(new_map);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder mybuilder = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    mybuilder.SetTitle("Bitmap Exception");
                    mybuilder.SetMessage(ex.Message);
                }
 }
```

Comment: there are many, many existing questions about converting an image to grayscale that don't require nested for loops.  Have you tried any of them?  https://www.google.com/search?q=android+convert+image+to+grayscale+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: I try as much as possible not to plagiarize my solutions. Lemme check them lout, Thank You for the time

Comment: the entire point of SO is to show you how other people have solved similar problems.  You are expected to search for existing answers before posting.

Comment: Okay noted, won't happen again in the future.